# Time complexity of Modulus

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory, modulo, modular

I have developed the following algorithm to compute ciphertext as :
of ciphertext c =s (rp+mi )  mod q, where p, q are random primes and s,r is a random number from Zp. I searched to find the running time for mod operation, I found it as O(n) and other reference says it is O (n^2), while I found the complexity of mod power i.e (s^d (rp+mi)mod p) is O(log n), which smaller than normal mod operation, please advise, is the values are correct?

Comment: Computing a/b and a%b at the same time has the same bitwise time complexity as multiplication, and the best known algorithm for that is O(n log n). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations .

Comment: Whether it's possible to do better if you compute a%b alone, without computing a/b I don't know (but I guess not).